# Error showing during rename columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

```
HSN.rename(columns={'HSN Code':'HSN','Quantity':'Total Quantity','Total Amount':'Total Value',

d:\Vishal\Udemy\PD Data\Vishal\Python\GSTR1\GSTR1.py:130: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Before renaming make a copy of the dataframe and then rename:

```
HSN_copy = HSN.copy()
HSN_copy.rename(columns=......
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use inplace=True within the rename function.